# A map containing std::strings and std::vector<Another_Struct>

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, struct

I'm literally smashing my brains out here because my code doesn't seem to be working. I have a struct which contains elements (call the struct A).

I have another struct (B) that looks like this:

```
struct B
{
    std::string m_strID;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<A>> m_mmap;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<A>> m_mmap1;

    B()
    {   
    }
};
```

I am trying to populate the maps using this as an example (say b is an instance of B and a an instance of type A):

```
b[a[i].anElement].m_mmap[a[i].anElement].push_back(a[i]);
```

And this is inside a for loop which I hoped would add to the value (which is a vector) the instance of `A` to the map... but it isn't, there is always 1 element in there even though i have 672 instances which should be inside :((((( any help?

Comment: Just `b.m_mmap[aVariableOfTypeA[i].anElement].push_back(fTypeA[i]);`

Comment: You're ... _literally smashing your brains out_?? Stop!!

Comment: Please do not name your variables `m_mmap` and `m_mmap1`.

Comment: It was a quick example - i don't.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use typedef:

```
struct B
{
   std::string m_strID;
   typedef std::vector<A> VectorOfA;
   typedef std::map<std::string, VectorOfA> MyMap;
   MyMap m_mmap;
   MyMap m_mmap1;

   B()
   {    
   }
};
```

It will not only save on typing but also will make your program more readable and less error prone.

To populate:

```
B b;
...
b.m_mmap[ aVariableOfTypeA[i].anElement ].push_back( aVariableOfTypeA[i] );
```

You said b is an instance of type B, so there is no reason to apply `[]` to b, as it is not array nor container.

Now `typedef` can also help you to understand whats wrong in your code and why you see only size 1:

```
B b;
std::cout << "size of map: " << b.m_mmap.size() << std::endl;
B::VectorOfA &vref = b.m_mmap[ somestring ];
std::cout << "size of vector:" << vref.size() << std::endl;
A &aref = v[0]; // first element
```

That code should help you to understand which type is where

Comment: Personally I find `std::vector<A>` more readable than `VectorOfA` !  The `MyMap` is a good idea though.

Comment: @MattMcNabb there are not many choices here as name A for a class is not a good idea. With better name for that type like `Person` that type can be called `Persons`. But here it was more to show the principle rather than good names.